# Determine if the Series Converges and Explain approach

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the series Convergent? Explain and find Sum:-

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ (2)^\frac{1}{n}-(2)^\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Thanks

Comment: Series converges if the sequence of partial sums converges. In this case it's easy to see that the partial sums are telescoping.

Answer (score 3):

**Show convergence**

You can use the [integral tests for convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) on this problem, because the integral of this function is fairly easy to determine. The integral test states that your series of the form:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) $$
converges if and only if the solution to the following integral is finite:
$$ \int_1^\infty f(x) dx $$
In your case $f(x)=2^{\frac{1}{x}}-2^\frac{1}{x+1}$ yields the following answer for the integral:
$$ \log (2) \left(\text{li}(2)-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)\right)+2 \sqrt{2}-3$$
where $\text{li}$ is the [logarithmic integral function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) and $\text{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

which is finite ($\approx 0.624$ if you evaluate it) so your function converges.

**Find sum**

If you write out a part of the series you can see that almost all terms will cancel:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \ (2)^\frac{1}{n}-(2)^\frac{1}{n+1} = 2^\frac{1}{1}-2^\frac{1}{2}+2^\frac{1}{2}-2^\frac{1}{3}+2^\frac{1}{3}-2^\frac{1}{4}+....+2^\frac{1}{N}-2^\frac{1}{N+1}$$
All terms except the very last and the very first drop out so you get:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} \ (2)^\frac{1}{n}-(2)^\frac{1}{n+1} = 2^\frac{1}{1}-2^\frac{1}{N+1}$$
now taking the limit for $N\to\infty$: $\lim_{N\to\infty} 2^{1/(N+1)} =1 $
so you get convergence to 1.

Obviously, the fact that you can find a finite value for this sum is already a proof in itself that the series is convergent.

Comment: Find sum part was enough for OP.

Comment: Instead of writing $2^{\frac{1}{\infty}}$, you should calculate the $n^{\text{th}}$ partial sum and then take a limit (as in tetori's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$\sum_{n=1}^N 2^{1/n}-2^{1/(n+1)} = 2-2^{1/(N+1)}$$
and 
$$\lim_{N\to\infty} 2^{1/(N+1)} =1,$$
so this series is convergent and  converges to 1.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider a series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ where $x_n=a_n-a_{n+1}$ for every $n\geqslant1$, for some sequence $(a_n)_{n\geqslant1}$.

- Express each partial sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^Nx_n$ with $N\geqslant1$, as a simple function of $a_1$ and of another term of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geqslant1}$.
- Deduce a simple condition implying that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^Nx_n$ converges when $N\to\infty$.
- When this condition is met, express the limit $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ in terms of  $(a_n)_{n\geqslant1}$.